# Is it possible to increase the number of tags shown as suggestions?

Tags: feature-request, tags

In, for example, https://law.stackexchange.com/, when I type some letters in the tag field, at most six suggestions come up.  My impression is that the other stack exchange sites are set at six too.  Is it possible to increase this number, either as a user or for the whole site?

Comment: I'm re-tagging this as a feature request, because it's not currently possible within the existing system.